# How can we find the file access permissions in NFS server using python util?

Tags: python, nfs, nfsclient

I want to check whether my current user has read access to a NFS file. One way to do it is to try to open the file using NFS util library libnfs. In this case, if user will not have read permission, an error will be thrown. However, this doesn't seem to be the right way, rather we should be checking for the access permission before trying to open a file.

I want to know if there is any python library to check the file permissions in NFS.

Comment: There's [nfs_access()](https://github.com/sahlberg/libnfs-python/blob/9b98a4da85351c388fa19002047bd33d7e483a85/libnfs/libnfs.i#L201)